# SSIS: Do package data sources update all connected connection managers automatically?

Tags: ssis, connection-string, datasource

I converted a big project from SSIS2008 -> SSIS2014

During conversion i also erased all connection managers and recreated them based on the packages data sources.

Now i want to test my packages on another server , so i changed my 2 data sources only.

When i open the packages can see on the connection-string the old server.

If i dont do anything else and press start, what will happen?

Will the package update itself automatically and get the connection string of the data source or not?

If it doesn't then what is the point to have the option "create connenction manager from data source" and assign a DataSourceID to the package connection manager?

*I am in package deployment model.*

Comment: You had SLSDB as a local Connection Manager. You deleted the local version and then created the Project Level Connection Manager, also called SLSDB. The question is, will the package automap from the local to the project level via name match? If so, the answer is no

Comment: I deleted the packge local connection manager. I created then a new connection manager based from data source. so?

Comment: You would have to open each package and do a find & replace the old conneciton GUID with the new connection GUID. It's a pain.

Comment: @Nick : Even if i do this, then later when i change the data source on project level, do the changes propagate to the package connection managers or not? This is the question.

Comment: We only use project deployment model so I can't say for sure... In project deployment model, we run all of our connection managers at the project level. So if a change happens to one of those connection managers, the change propogates down to the packages that reference that connection (by GUID in the XML). I would think this would be the same for you.

Comment: Although this is true, project level configuration does not serve well when in development , since you may want to run some packages on another server and some on another ofr  the same data source.